# Counting the letters (uppercase and lowercase) of a string

Tags: java, file-io, for-loop

I have here a program that enters a paragraph and writes it into a file. After that, it should count the occurrences of each letters (case sensitive). However, it doesn't count the number of letter occurrences. I think I put the  `for` loop in the wrong place.

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;
public class Exercise1 {

    public static int countLetters (String line, char alphabet) {
        int count = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i <= line.length()-1; i++) {
            if (line.charAt(i) == alphabet)
                count++;
        }
        return count;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        BufferedReader buffer = new BufferedReader (new InputStreamReader(System.in));
        PrintWriter outputStream = null;
        Scanner input = new Scanner (System.in);
        int total;

        try {
            outputStream = new PrintWriter (new FileOutputStream ("par.txt"));
            System.out.println("How many lines are there in the paragraph you'll enter?");
            int lines = input.nextInt();
            System.out.println("Enter the paragraph: ");
            String paragraph = buffer.readLine();
            outputStream.println(paragraph);
            int j;
            for (j = 1; j<lines; j++) {
                paragraph = buffer.readLine();
                outputStream.println(paragraph);    
            }
            outputStream.close();
            System.out.println("The paragraph is written to par.txt");

            for (int k=1; k<lines; k++) {
                paragraph = buffer.readLine();
                total = countLetters (paragraph, 'A');
                if (total != 0)
                    System.out.println("A: "+total);
                            //I'll do bruteforce here up to lowercase z

            }
        }

        catch(FileNotFoundException e) {
            System.out.println("Error opening the file par.txt");
        }

    }

}
```

Please help me fix the code. I'm new in programming and I need help. Thank you very much!

Comment: This won't solve your problem, but instead of bruteforcing all the letters, I would recommend wrapping your `for (int k=1; k<lines; k++)` in `private final char[] alpha = {'A','B',...,'a','b',...}; for(char letter : alpha) { /* Your For Loop Here */ }`. This will make your code way easier to read by the time you get finished.

Comment: Thanks @gobernador!Let me see if I get this right. I'll declare `private final char[] alpha = {'A','B',...,'a','b',...}; ` and what `for` loop will I put inside `for(char letter : alpha)`?

Comment: The last one. The one where you mentioned bruteforcing up to lowercase z. Then, you'll call `total = countLetters(paragraph, letter);`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First, your initial reading user input is a bit of a waste since you read once then enter the for loop for the rest - this is not a problem, just a better code.

```
// your code
String paragraph = buffer.readLine();
outputStream.println(paragraph);
int j;
for (j = 1; j<lines; j++) {
     paragraph = buffer.readLine();
     outputStream.println(paragraph);    
 }
```

You can just put them in the loop:

```
// better code
String paragraph;
int j;
for (j = 0; j<lines; j++) {
     paragraph = buffer.readLine();
     outputStream.println(paragraph);    
}
```

Then your first problem comes from the way you read the lines:

```
// your code - not working
outputStream.close();
for (int k=1; k<lines; k++) {
      paragraph = buffer.readLine();
      total = countLetters (paragraph, 'A');
```

Consider what happened above:

- The input is already **DONE**, the output is already written and stream is closed - up to here everything is good
- Then when you try to count the number of characters, you do: `paragraph = buffer.readLine();` - what does this code do? It waits for another user input (instead of reading what's been inserted)

To fix the problem above: you need to read from what's **already** been written - not asking for another input. Then instead of brute forcing every character one by one, you can just put them into a list and write a for loop.

So now, you want to read from the existing file that you already created (ie. reading what WAS inputted by the user):

```
BufferedReader fileReader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(new File("par.txt")));

String allCharacters = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ";
String aLineInFile;

// Read the file that was written earlier (whose content comes from user input)
// This while loop will go through line-by-line in the file
while((aLineInFile = fileReader.readLine()) != null)
{
      // For every line in the file, count number of occurrences of characters  
      // This loop goes through every character (a-z and A-Z)  
      for(int i = 0; i < allCharacters.length(); i++)
      {
            // For each single character, check the number of occurrences in the current line
            String charToLookAt = String.valueOf(allCharacters.charAt(i));
            int numOfCharOccurancesInLine = countLetters (aLineInFile, charToLookAt);

            System.out.println("For line: " + aLineInFile + ", Character: " + charToLookAt + " appears: " + numOfCharOccurancesInLine + " times " );
      }         
}
```

The above gives you the number of occurrences of every character in every line - now you just need to organize them to keep track of how many are in total for the whole file.

Code-wise, there might be better way to write this to have cleaner implementation, but the above is easy to understand (and I just wrote it very quickly).

Comment: Thanks, TS! So this `alignInFile` is different from my `paragraph`?

Comment: paragraph was INPUT - came from the user - this was a-line-in-file which is basically reading your file line-by-line

Comment: Thanks again! How can I go through every line? I'm sorry; it's just that I'm not yet familiar with Java syntax.

Comment: look at the edited - the while loop goes through the file line-by-line. So that variable aLineInFile represents a line from the file

Comment: Thank you! But the string charToLookAt doesn't match the character `alphabet`. I cannot typecast String to char as well.

Comment: what do you mean? You use String.valueOf to convert char to String. and what do you mean the character alphabet?

Comment: Even though there's a String.valueOf, Eclipse says `The method countLetters(String, char) in the type Exercise1 is not applicable for the arguments (String, String)`

Comment: Oh never mind! I was able to convert it into a char. :) Thank you so much for making me undertand this!

Comment: Oh sorry - I assumed the countLetters was (String, String)

Answer (score 0):

Do everything in one loop:

```
       for (j = 1; j<lines; j++) {
            paragraph = buffer.readLine();
            total = countLetters (paragraph, 'A');
            if (total != 0)
                System.out.println("A: "+total);
            outputStream.println(paragraph);    
        }
```

Comment: Hello JMelnik! I tried it but for example I want three line, after the first line, it stops and writes that line to par.txt already. It does not even count the number of A's.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a HashTable for count each case sentitive letters :

```
        final Pattern patt = Pattern.compile("A-Za-z]");
        final HashMap<Character, Integer> tabChar = new HashMap<Character, Integer>(
            52);

        // replace : paragraph = buffer.readLine();
        // Unless you use it outside, you can declare it 'final'
        final char[] paragraph = "azera :;,\nApOUIQSaOOOF".toCharArray();


        for (final Character c : paragraph ) {
            if (Character.isLetter(c)) {
                Integer tot = tabChar.get(c);
                tabChar.put(c, (null == tot) ? 1 : ++tot);
            }
        }
```

Output :

```
{F=1, A=1, O=4, I=1, U=1, Q=1, S=1, e=1, a=3, r=1, p=1, z=1}
```

You can use `final TreeSet<Character> ts = new TreeSet(tabChar.keySet());` to sort the characters and then `get(c);` them from `tabChar`

Answer (score 0):

The previous answers would have solved your problem but another way of avoiding brute force might be to use a loop using ASCII character value.